# Why is built library so much bigger in size?

Tags: compiler-construction, build, size, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have downloaded a C++ library which is about 450 MB in size. After building, the library takes about 2 GB. Why such big difference ? Where did all the extra size go to ?

My question is more philosophical than technical. I don't seek an exact answer to my particular software issue, but rather a general explanation to why library sizes may differ across different build scenarios.

Comment: My question is more philosophical than technical really. I am new to using and building 3rd party libraries and making my own builds. Therefore I don't seek the exact answer to my particular software issue, but rather a general explanation to why size of library increases that much. Thank you =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one thing that may be in common across many software development languages and compilers is that a **debug** version of any library will be different to a **release** version.

A release version is typically built with size and performance in mind, and a release version is likely to be optimised, symbols might be stripped, and additional code, memory guards, debug helpers, et cetera, maybe removed from the source (e.g., in the C family, via means of pre-processor defines).

Note however, that this doesn't *always* imply that a chunk of release code will be smaller than its debug counterpart. For example, in the search for performance, speaking of the C family again, loops might be unrolled - resulting in code which is faster but larger.